# select between 2 tables and find the user

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql database. **comments(comments_id, user)** and table **comments_reply(reply_id, comments_id, reply_flag, reply_user_id)**

Table comments holds the comment id and the user id that posted a comment.
First table may be like **comments(1315, 23)**

Many users can reply to this comment and their details are stored in comments_reply table.
Second table may be like **comments_reply(1, 1315, 1, 23)**
                                    ...**(2, 1315, 1, 30)**

I want to select reply_user_id from table comments_reply where reply_flag=1 and also this user exists in table comments and is the user that posts comment 1315.

Any idea if this can be done and what is the sql query for this?

Comment: you mean, find users that replied to their own comments?

Comment: yes exactly this is what I mean

Comment: What should your result look like? Do you have example data?

Comment: I just want the right select query. Then it is ok to work with it in my php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve user who commented their own comment:

```
select
    cr.reply_user_id

from
    comments_reply cr join comments c on cr.comments_id = c.comments_id and cr.reply_user_id = c.user

where
    cr.reply_flag = 1

group by
    cr.reply_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cr.reply_user_id 
FROM comments_reply AS cr, comments AS c
WHERE cr.reply_flag=1 AND cr.reply_user_id = c.user AND c.comments = 1315 AND c.comments = cr.comments_id
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM comments_reply cr, comments c
WHERE reply_flag = 1 AND cr.comments_id = c.comments_id AND c.comments_id = 1315
```

Comment: The user is missing here. This query doesn't only return comments with own replies, instead returns all comments (i  this case 1315) with any reply.